# What is the relation between a DecorView and ViewRootImpl in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-framework

I am not sure I understand the relation between the two.
As I understand ViewRootImpl holds mView which is the main view per window, and DecorView is also the main view per window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that the mView inside ViewRootImpl IS DecorView so this answers my own question

Answer (score 2):

ViewRootImpl is the top of the view hierarchy, it implements the needed protocol between View and the WindowManager.

DecorView is the true root of the Window's view hierarchy. 
It contains both the "decor" (i.e. the window's title, and also contains the content view.

[image]
[image]